# How to change the ad-hoc WiFi name in OSX?

Tags: macos, wifi, network, airport

When I turn on Internet Sharing on my mac, the broadcasted network name is the original Computer Name of the iMac.

The computer name has since been changed, however the WiFi name continues to be broadcast as the original which I really need to change. I've looked everywhere in System Preferences for the original computer name but can't find any remnant of it.

Can anyone please tell me how to change the ad-hoc WiFi name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lion and Snow Leopard, you can create a network from the AirPort menu and choose whatever SSID you please.

[image]

The same dialog should be available from the network preference pane in System Preferences if you prefer that avenue.

Comment: **Thank you!**  I found the screen shown above via the Sys Prefs route (Network > Wi-Fi > Create New '+') and entered details for the new connection, then removed the old one.  For some reason the AirPort Utility is not working for me - says it can not find any AirPort wireless devices.  Seems like that is looking for an AirPort router, so I must not be using the right utility - regardless your suggestion of going through Sys Prefs worked.  Thanks for helping an OSX newb.

Comment: Welcome to the site - do read up on the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) and join in the chat once you have enough reputation. In general - we thank with votes and picking answers (you're on the right track). As to airport utility - that only exists to configure the stand alone network hardware - not so much to change things on your mac. I don't think it's explained well - just something everyone picks up over time.

Comment: You can also change it by going to **Sharing > Uncheck Internet Sharing > Wi-Fi Options...**